# I can't change Value of Variable using match media in Javascript

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I just defined a variable called "option" for my Intersection Observer Threshold but it's not changing when I'm using match media.

here's the code :

```
{
let option = {threshold:0.8};
let mediaQuery1 = window.matchMedia('(min-width:1250px)');
if(mediaQuery1.matches){
       option.threshold= 1;
}
```

Comment: Please check the window.width by opening the console drawer below the browser so that you can check if window.width == min-width . Both the widths should be equal for the matches flag to be true;

Comment: For example if widow.width = 1250 & window.matchMedia('(min-width:1250)') then you get mediaQuery1.matches == true.

Comment: @Aakif it show that width matches but it's not changing the variable